# Questions tagged with same tags on Movies stack to show on SFF stack chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

This is a bit of a tricky one to describe; please bear with me...

---

There is a feature which exists whereby any question tagged with [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) or [fantasy](/questions/tagged/fantasy) in the [**Movies & TV stack**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) appear in the **[Sci-Fi & Fantasy stack's][1]** chat room: [Mos Eisley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20474778#20474778).

**The problem**

... is that only *those* specific tags are shown, when there are users from the SFF stack which can answer many other questions in the M&TV stack. E.G. [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) or [the-matrix](/questions/tagged/the-matrix) or [x-men](/questions/tagged/x-men) etc.

[See this comment stream for a bit of background](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/switch-in-the-matrix-two-actors#comment47916_30884).

Whilst it is completely valid to have a question of those topics posted on **either** stack, it is much more visible to specifically-skilled users from the SFF stack to answer questions on those topics on the M&TV stack.

**The Request**

**If a question is asked on the M&TV stack and it gets tagged with *any* or *some*<sub>1</sub> existing tags in the SFF stack, then can that question be posted in [Mos Eisley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)<sub>2</sub> please?**

So; let's say a question gets asked on M&TV and is tagged with [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) but **not** with [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction) or [fantasy](/questions/tagged/fantasy), this question currently will *not* show-up on the SFF chat room<sub>3</sub>; my request is that it does.

**The concerns**

- The main thing I can think of is that this will create *noise* in the SFF chat room, which I'm sure this isn't really a problem.

---

**1.** Maybe the most popular 15-20 tags or something like that.

**2.** And vice versa if you'd like.

**3.** This *isn't* a problem per se, a Q asked on M&TV has a huge collection of awesome users who will be able to answer it!

Comment: Haha, thanks for that 3rd footnote, though. But I wonder if this isn't better asked on [meta.scifi.se].

Comment: @ChristianRau Well, it sort-of spans two different stacks, so I htought I'd go to the parent here.

Comment: But it's a feature that doesn't require any broader SE-framework support, any SciFi mod or chat owner can add any feeds he wants and it is simply to that community alone to decide about the those feeds. Neither is it really of concern to Movies.SE or any other community what tags the SciFi chat tracks.

Comment: In addition to that, I'd surmise (based on the past few days) that this question won't gather the necessary attention here at all, whereas on [meta.scifi.se] where the people sit who should and can actually decide about this, it will reach some answers pretty fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Use RSS Feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss)**

This is not a case where the functionality needs to be changed by the Dev team or anything; there is already the functionality where a 'chat bot' posts qustions from certain RSS feeds.

These RSS feeds can be set-up by any mod in the chat room of the site.

In this particular case, [I posted this request to our mods](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6754/21267), and the feeds were set-up.